# Can pair programming work under Scrum iterations

Tags: scrum, extreme-programming

Is it possible? 
Or in a more generic question, can XP work under Scrum iterations?

Comment: **Yes.** Is there more context to your question? Why would you think the answer might be “no?”

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In fact, it has been said a number of times by the creators that the reason they didn't specify how to do the work in the sprint is because they wanted it to be open to different types of work and they felt like the problem was already solved by other solutions (like XP).